# Enforce intersection of generic types to extend a given type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following (non-compiling) TypeScript example:

```
type Optional<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] };

interface Foo {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

function foo<A extends Optional<Foo>, B extends Optional<Foo>, A & B extends Foo>(a: A, b: B) : Foo {
    return {...a, ...b};
}
```

The idea of `foo` is to take two partial instances of `Foo` and enforce that their intersection (at least) extends `Foo`.

Is there a possible way to construct such a constraint?

If that was possible, is it possible to extend the solution to a flexible amount of argument? I.e. `foo` not only taking 2 arguments, but `n` arguments.

```
function foo<A extends Optional<Foo>[]>(a: ...A) : Foo {
    ...
}
```

Comment: FYI your `Optional` already exists: [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype).

Comment: `function foo<K extends keyof Foo>(a: Pick<Foo, K>, b: Omit<Foo, K>) : Foo { return {...a, ...b} as Foo; }` works fine for clients, but requires a type cast: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884

Comment: @lesiak nice! can that be generalised to a flexible amount of parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a tuple type for a rest parameter that requires all that all properties of the last element in the tuple contains any properties that haven't already been specified:

```
interface Foo {
    name: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    id: number
}

function foo<A extends Partial<Foo>= {}, B extends Omit<Foo, keyof A> = Omit<Foo, keyof A>>(...a: [...A[], B]) : Foo {
    return Object.assign({}, ...a) as Foo;
}

let x = foo({ name: "" }, { lastName: "" }, { id: 0, age: 1})
let x2 = foo({ name: "" }) // error
let x4 = foo({ name: "" }, { lastName: "" }, { id: 0 }) // error
let x3 = foo() // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gNwHHIA2cdAcuVbXpNWhYnEYCQAVzIAjaCPbAAJtWlzoBAL4ECMKSARhg6EMhiYAPAEFkEAB6QQymsgAKcKMbgdLGdAB8ALw4WgA0yABCdo4Qzq4A8mTAYH6YEQDWEACe6DDI1gHIIUkpaeiZOXkFAQEAFAB0TXDUANpNDdatALoRkd0AlMjU-jhsxFAQYFJQZgmyAFYQRg3cNMCMIHXY4cgdcEPcaJgiOvgEHFPI9sXmmNsk-NQARM-Iu9ic3GB8FC9vH2QKmoAAYIuIBABGLQDC5XewAJluFnQD1If2Qr3eQwA9Di7FAoOgoHCwNcACzI+6fdECLGAri8J6YgERT7A5Ag7HIPEEokk-CXMn2ADMVNRuPx0H5QA)

Although the errors might be a bit hard to read

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I am wondering if the `Partial<Foo> &` is really required as part of `B`'s constraint or if `B extends Omit<Foo, keyof A>` is enough.

Comment: @user3612643 Yeah you are right. It's not necessary. I added it because I thought it would be important to get suggestions for all properties (not just the ones that aren't specified yet) but you seem to get that either way. So it can be removed

Comment: Just found a bug: `let x3 = foo({ name: "" })` compiles, but shouldn't.

Comment: @user3612643 Fixed. Since there was only one element there was nowhere to infer `A` from and it defaulted to `Partial<Foo>`, which had all keys of `Foo`.

Comment: very good! rocks perfectly